# Are the following functionalities possible with the Outlook Add-in development?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am looking into the development of an Outlook Add-in using the Office Add-in platform. I would like to know if the following functionalities will be possible to be implemented using this platform:

1. New email received event
2. New email sent event
3. Email read event
4. Email save event

The add-in could come in the form of a notification box or print to console. Thanks!

Comment: Outlook Web Add-in work on particular email or calendar event item. Events which you mentioned are more mailbox level events and it won't be possible to watch or listen to them from Outlook Add-in. For (4), if you are asking how to save current email item from Outlook Add-in, then you can look at this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#saveAsync_callback_

Comment: Hi Outlook Add-ins Team, thank you for the prompt reply and clarification. Another question - is the Outlook add-in able to run in offline mode, or will there be complications with the integration of the Office JS API?

Comment: Outlook Web Add-ins won't run in offline mode. (since add-ins are hosted on a web server, the user needs to be online to access them)

Comment: Also, with reference to your first reply regarding the limitations of Outlook Add-in with mailbox level events, is it also safe to assume that the below events are also not possible to be implemented with Outlook add-in:
1. Outlook new main window event
2. Outlook new inspector window event
3. Item in Outbox folder event before it is shifted to the Sent Box folder
4. Item added into the Sent box folder event

Comment: No, currently add-in cannot listen to these events. Related to email send, we have this feature, please check it is applicable to your use-case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and straight to the point reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Outlook Web Add-in work on particular email or calendar event item. Events which you mentioned are more mailbox level events and it won't be possible to watch or listen to them from Outlook Add-in. For (4), if you are asking how to save current email item from Outlook Add-in, then you can look at this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#saveAsync_callback_
2. Outlook Web Add-ins won't run in offline mode. (since add-ins are hosted on a web server, the user needs to be online to access them)
3. No, currently add-in cannot listen to these events. Related to email send, we have this feature, please check it is applicable to your use-case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows